# Java Program emits an error beep sound when key combination is pressed

Tags: java, awt, keypress, keylistener

I have code that generates projectiles corresponding to different directions of a boat sailing on the ocean. The direction is determined by the speeds of the object, looping clockwise where 0 is north through 7 as North West. In My keyPressed function, I can move around with the arrow keys just fine. Furthermore, If I press the space button to activate the cannons, everything works well, except if I'm heading north west. In this case, no bullet is fired, and my java program emits a little beep.

The keyPressed code

```
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { //TODO switch to keyBindings to remove pause after the initial key press
    // if the key is pressed, move up
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        //move the board down.
        dy = speed;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        // move spaceship upwards
        dy = -speed;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        dx = -speed;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        dx = speed;
    }
    dir = myShip.getDirection(dx, dy); // determine direction so that the draw function can draw the correct sprite.
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_I){ // info key.
        System.out.println(getCurrentTile().getClass().getName()); 
        Tile t = getCurrentTile();
        if(t.isDockTile()){
            Docks d = (Docks) t;
            System.out.println(d.getName());
        }
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_M && getCurrentTile().isDockTile()){ 
        if(getCurrentTile().isDockTile()){
            mission = new Mission(); // create a new mission.
            Docks d = (Docks) getCurrentTile();
            mission.init(d); // initialize using the dock's name.
            isMissionAssigned = true; // yay! we have a Mission!
        } else {
            System.out.println("You can't get a mission if you're not at a port!");
        }
    }
    // fire a bullet 
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){ // TODO - NW seems to be broken.     
            bullet = new Projectile(bulletSpeed, dir, 10);
            System.out.println("Created a bullet with direction " + dir);
            bullet2 = new Projectile(bulletSpeed, myShip.getOppDir(dir), 10);

    }       
}
```

And my two functions for getting the Direction of the ship.

```
public int getOppDir(int d){
    // since there are 4 directions, add 4 to get opposite.
    // use opposite to move back to 0 if > than 8
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        d++;
        if(d >= 8){
            d = 0;
        }
    }
    return d;

}

public int getDirection(int dx, int dy){ // determines the direction the ship is facing based on speeds.
    // 0 = N, 1 = ne, 2 = e, 3 = se, 4 = s, 5 = sw, 6 = w, 7 = nw
    int tempDir = 0;
    if( dx == 0 && dy < 0){
        // north
        tempDir = 0;
    } else if(dx == 0 && dy > 0){
        // south
        tempDir = 4;

    } else if(dx > 0 && dy == 0){
        // east
        tempDir = 2;
    } else if(dx > 0 && dy < 0){
        // ne
        tempDir = 1;
    } else if( dx > 0 && dy > 0)    {
        // se
        tempDir = 3;
    } else if(dx < 0 && dy == 0){
        // west
        tempDir = 6;            
    } else if (dx < 0 && dy < 0){
        //northWest
        tempDir = 7;
    } else if(dx < 0 && dy > 0){
        //south west
        tempDir = 5;
    }
    return tempDir; 
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT : I think this turned out to be a hardware problem. Shifting to ASDW controlls instead of the Arrow keys solved the problem.

Comment: Add a break point, fire up the debugger, step through the code...

Comment: There's no problem with this code. Look elsewhere. (To add 4 to a direction, use `return (d + 4)%8;`.)

Comment: Alright, I'll take a look through. I found that it simply doesn't like the space-bar to be pressed at the same time as up and left; even without any code within, it still gives me a beeping sound.

Comment: Turns out to be a hardware problem, I think. I found this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_%28computing%29#Control_processor which explains some rollover effect with the wiring within a keyboard creating phantom key presses. I don't know if that was the true problem or not, but shifting to asdw instead of arrow keys fixed this problem.